# Cypress browser support

Tags: node.js, browser, cypress

In the default cypress framework, we have plugins.js -> index.js the below code, and they've listed only chromium and electron browsers. Do we need to add more or is this okay the way it is?
From this picture, it looks like cypress supports only chromium and electron? But while we run 99% of cases we run it in Chrome. It is by default choosing chrome.

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />
// ***********************************************************
// This example plugins/index.js can be used to load plugins
//
// You can change the location of this file or turn off loading
// the plugins file with the 'pluginsFile' configuration option.
//
// You can read more here:
// https://on.cypress.io/plugins-guide
// ***********************************************************

const cucumber = require("cypress-cucumber-preprocessor").default;

// This function is called when a project is opened or re-opened (e.g. due to
// the project's config changing)

/**
 * @type {Cypress.PluginConfig}
 */
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  require("cypress-mochawesome-reporter/plugin")(on);
};
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on("file:preprocessor", cucumber());

  // cypress/plugins/index.js

  on("before:browser:launch", (browser = {}, launchOptions) => {
    console.log(launchOptions.args);
    if (browser.family === "chromium" && browser.name !== "electron") {
      launchOptions.args.push("--start-fullscreen");
      launchOptions.args.push("--window-size=1400,1200");

      return launchOptions;
    }

    if (browser.name === "electron") {
      launchOptions.preferences.fullscreen = true;

      return launchOptions;
    }
  });

  module.exports = (on, config) => {
    on("before:browser:launch", (browser, launchOptions) => {
      if (browser.name === "chrome" && browser.isHeadless) {
        launchOptions.args.push("--disable-gpu");
        return launchOptions;
      }
      
    });
  };

  // `on` is used to hook into various events Cypress emits
  // `config` is the resolved Cypress config
};
```

Comment: what is the command you are using to run the tests ?

Comment: 1st I use: npx cypress open. After this I run from cypress window

Comment: You can change the available browsers from here - https://imgur.com/a/D1hIbMF. For the browser to be available in the dropdown. you have to install that browser in your local machine.

Comment: yeap I know that. My exact question is, What should we store in plugins.js->index.js file?

How should it look like? If we can change it from  imgur.com/a/D1hIbMF why then we need plugins.js->index.js?

Answer (score 3):

In the top right corner of the cypress window you should be able to choose which browser you want to run.
You can also specify which browser you want to use in that index.js file. Here is an example:

```
module.exports = (on, config) => {
// inside config.browsers array each object has information like
// {
//   name: 'chrome',
//   channel: 'canary',
//   family: 'chromium',
//   displayName: 'Canary',
//   version: '80.0.3966.0',
//   path:
//    '/Applications/Canary.app/Contents/MacOS/Canary',
//   majorVersion: 80
// }
return {
  browsers: config.browsers.filter((b) => b.family === 'chromium'),
 }
}
```

See cypress docs for more: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/launching-browsers#Customize-available-browsers

Comment: yeap I know that. My exact question is, What should we store in plugins.js->index.js file? How should it look like? If we can change it from cypress window why then do we need plugins.js->index.js?

Comment: When adding this to the index.js file you are setting the default browser that you want the test to run in when not using the cypress window. If you are happy to change it from the test runner then you dont need to do anything in your index.js file @Luna